# Will be storing a list in redis more efficient than a lot of keys?

Tags: redis

Suppose, that I have a lot of (tens millions) of keys like this: A_1, A_2, A_3 etc; B_1, B_2 and so on. Values are all short int numbers. Now I am storing all this keys separately, perfomance is very good, but I have huge memory overhead. Not enough 12 Gb RAM and I need ten times more. I suppose, that I could use lists and storing something like that: key: A, list: [1, 2, 3, ...]. Can I win some memory using this approach insteed of millions separate keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably try for Redis Hash data structure

`like HSET superkey key value`

A hash key with few fields use less memory then a few different keys.
small hashes internally use ziplist which are more memory efficient and fast in search

There are some links you should look before choosing an approach

**Use hashes when possible**

[Redis Memory Optimization](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization)

**Storing hundreds of millions of simple key-value pairs in Redis**

[Tumbler: Storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs)

Comment: Yeah, hashes are 10 times better than plain keys. Does lists provide such perfomance?